# Change registerForm value ( boolean to number )

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

So I got a little issue understanding how to cast a boolean to number

**Problem :**

I' ve been trying to cast my `registerForm.value.aleas` which is a checkbox to a number ( 0 false, 1 true ),  to do a `POST` method (the `API` expect **1** or **0** value ) but I can't find a way to do it since `registerForm.value` always return me his default value ( **false** if checkbox isn't clicked and **true** is she is ).

**What I've tried :**

I've tried using `? 1 : 0` but I don't think `registerForm` accept it and I don't see any other way

**Code sample :**

*app.component.ts*

```
  postParams(){
const token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
const aleas = this.registerForm.value.aleas? 1 : 0;
return this.httpClient.post(`this.url?token=`,
  {
    token: token.token,
    is_alea_chantier: aleas,

  })
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("POST PARAMS DONE",data)
    },
    error => {
      console.log("POST PARAMS FAILED", error)
    }

  )
}


get f() {
 return this.registerForm.controls;
  }

onSubmit{
  this.submitted = true;
  console.log(this.registerForm.value.title)
  //stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.registerForm.invalid){
    console.log("INVALID FORM")
     return;
   } else {
    console.log("VALID FORM")
    this.postParams();
   }
 }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
    <input formControlName="aleas" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" 
    name="example1">
  </form>
</div>
```

Don't hesitate to tell me if you need anything else if anyone can lead me on the right way I'd really appreciate it, thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

Every answers work, but it seems to be a backend problem now, thank you!

Comment: You can retrieve the value of your aleas form control and cast it to a Number like this: `Number(this.registerForm.get("aleas").value)`

Comment: Use : `const aleas =  this.registerForm.controls['aleas'].value ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @GilleQ. it now shows only `null`

Comment: @NicholasK getting only `null`

Comment: It worked for me. How are you initializing the form-group? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @NicholasK my bad on this one, it works as expected I did a `console.log(aleas)` and it shows me as a number but it nows seems like a back-end problem, thank you!

Comment: No worries. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct syntax to access the value from the *form-control*:

```
const aleas = this.registerForm.controls['aleas'].value ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I like more my aproach :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few method to convert your boolean to a number, that works either with the compiler and at runtime, but you need to get the value of your formControl the right way before that.

```
const aleasFirst = this.registerForm.get("aleas").value ? 1 : 0; // your method
const aleasSecond = Number(this.registerForm.get("aleas").value);
const aleasThird = +this.registerForm.get("aleas").value; // unary operator
```

Comment: Thank you, each of those works as exepected but I have a backend problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As a formControl exist even you has no a control, you can use ngModel inside the form

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" 
    name="example1" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
       [ngModel]="registerForm.get('aleas').value==1" 
       (ngModelChange)="registerForm.get('aleas').setValue($event?1:0)">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's an interesting one I didn't knew about